# iOS: Receiver of message 'frame' is nil

Tags: ios, logic, frame, cgrect

When I analyze my code, I get the following Logic Error:

The receiver of message 'frame' is nil and returns a value of type 'CGRect' that will be garbage.

on these two lines:

```
CGRect rectFrame = purchaseCell.lblValue.frame;
CGRect rectFrameBG = purchaseCell.lblValueBG.frame;
```

The code works great, but just trying to figure out what this is saying.  Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:  Here is the full method:

```
purchaseCell.lblHeader.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNextLTPro-Regular" size:16];
purchaseCell.lblHeader.text = curField.fieldName;
purchaseCell.lblValue.text = curField.fieldValue;
purchaseCell.lblValueBG.text = curField.fieldValue;
purchaseCell.lblValue.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNextLTPro-Regular" size:16];
purchaseCell.lblValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
purchaseCell.lblValueBG.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[purchaseCell.lblValueBG sizeToFit];
[purchaseCell.lblValue sizeToFit];
CGRect rectFrame = purchaseCell.lblValue.frame;
CGRect rectFrameBG = purchaseCell.lblValueBG.frame;
NSLog(@"RectFrame X:  %.2f", rectFrame.origin.x);

purchaseCell.lblValue.frame = CGRectMake(rectFrame.origin.x-rectFrame.size.width,rectFrame.origin.y, rectFrame.size.width+14, rectFrame.size.height);
frameSizeWidth = rectFrame.size.width;
purchaseCell.lblValueBG.frame = CGRectMake(rectFrameBG.origin.x-rectFrameBG.size.width,rectFrameBG.origin.y, rectFrameBG.size.width+14, rectFrameBG.size.height);
```

Comment: My guess: It would seem to indicate that `purchaseCell`, `purchaseCell.lblValue` or `purchaseCell.lblValueBG` can be `nil` in some scenarios or at least the compiler thinks it could be. In these cases `.frame` would be sent to a `nil` object which could return illegal values. You might want to check if this is possible (even if it is only a border case). If it is not this warning could stem from the limited ability of the compiler to predict what code paths will be taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyzer is saying that

```
purchaseCell.lblValue
```

evaluates to `nil`, so no sensible value can be assigned to `rectFrame`. What are you doing with `purchaseCell` and it's properties elsewhere in the code?

The "receiver" means the object that is receiving the "frame" message.

It looks like there is probably some code branch where the cell or its lblValue property could be nil, and the analyser doesn't like it. @StilesCrisis' suggestion of checking for a nil value and returning if so will probably clear it out for you (and prevent any possible error), if you can't find what the real cause is.

Comment: I am doing some special resizing of lblValue and lblValueBG and I need the current frame to start with so I can create the new CGRect.  It all works.  rectFrame does get the frame object from lblValue perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you include the rest of the method in your question or is it 27 pages long?

Comment: okay I updated the op, basically, every time the test in lblValue gets updated, the background label around it needs to be resized and since the font I am using shifts from where I locate it in the xib, I have to do some special shifting in the code

Comment: Probably there is some edge case where it really could be nil. I would suggest checking at the top of the method if it is nil, and if so, just return immediately.

Comment: @StilesCrisis agree, this will be some analyzer spaghetti

Comment: Yes I added the check and it no longer complains if(purchaseCell.lblValue == nil || purchaseCell.lblValueBG==nil)
        return purchaseCell;

Comment: Hang on, you're _returning_ purchaseCell? I assumed that was an ivar and you were just modifying some properties on it?